# What is the best way to create alias to attributes in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

What is the best way to create an alias to a instance atribute in Ruby (I'm not using rails or any ruby gem, just, Ruby).
For example given the class below, how can I create an alias to the `:student_name` attribute accessors?

```
class Student
  attr_accessor :student_name
  alias :name :student_name    #wrong
end

s = Student.new
s.student_name = "Jordan"
puts s.name  # --> Jordan
s.name = "Michael" # --> NoMethodError: undefined method `name=' for #<Student:0x572394> ...
```

Thank's guys!

Answer (score 34):

add

```
alias :name :student_name    # not wrong, only for getter
alias :name= :student_name=  # add this for setter
alias :name? :student_name?  # add this for boolean
```

Answer (score 19):

**For Rails**

`alias_attribute new_name, old_name`

Source http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/AttributeMethods/ClassMethods.html#method-i-alias_attribute

**Use case:** When you, most likely, want to change the attribute name without changing schema and without breaking existing functionality

Comment: The original question clearly stated "I'm not using rails" and this solution only works for those using Rails.

Comment: This solution also has an error (or at least it is not clear).  The correct code should use symbols:  `alias_attribute :new_name, :old_name`

Answer (score 14):

As John points out, you need to alias both the reader and the writer. This being Ruby, it's quite easy to define your own alias method to handle this for you.

```
class Module
  def alias_attr(new_attr, original)
    alias_method(new_attr, original) if method_defined? original
    new_writer = "#{new_attr}="
    original_writer = "#{original}="
    alias_method(new_writer, original_writer) if method_defined? original_writer
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm just being picky here but I would prefer to call it alias_attr to be consistent with alias_method. This way both would be of the form alias_thingtoalias.