# how to pass parameters to an alias method in ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, alias

I want to create a alias method in ruby and pass parameters to this. I managed to do the following

```
class User
  def say_name
    puts "I'm sameera"
  end
end

class User
  alias :tell_name :say_name
  def say_name
    puts "I'm sameera gayan"
    tell_name
  end
end

user = User.new
user.say_name
```

and it gives me the out put as

I'm sameera gayan
I'm sameera

But now i want to pass my name as a parameter to the first 'say_name' method. So the new code will be like

```
class User
  def say_name(name)
    puts "#{name}"
  end
end

class User
  alias :tell_name :say_name(name)
  def say_name(name)
    puts "I'm sameera gayan"
    tell_name(name)
  end
end

user = User.new
user.say_name("my new name")
```

But now this doesn't work (passing parameter to alias method). So my question is how to pass parameters to an alias method.

I hope this question is clear to you. Thanks in advance

cheers

sameera

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried this one and came to this solution

```
class User

        def say_name(name)

              puts "#{name}"

        end

end

class User

        alias :tell_name :say_name

        def say_name(name)

              puts "Hi"

              tell_name(name)

        end

end

user = User.new

user.say_name("Rohit")
```

The reason this is working because we cannot pass arguments to aliases. And that is what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

I'm learning Ruby. So when I saw this question I decided to try it. Though I have yet to learn about aliasing methods in detail I came across a solution. Don't know if it is the way it should be done. And can't say why it is so yet. May be in a few days after I have learn't in depth I'll add it. For now, here is a working solution.

```
class User
  attr_accessor :name
  def say_name
    puts "#{name}"
  end
end

class User
  alias :tell_name :say_name
  def say_name
    puts "I'm sameera gayan"
    tell_name
  end
end

user = User.new
user.name = "Sameera"
user.say_name
```

[This qtn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913349/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-alias-to-attributes-in-ruby) also helped me in the process.

Comment: This looks correct.  Aliases don't take parameters, as sameera tried.  They just make another name for the method.

Comment: hi Christy

Thanks for the reply. But in my case I'm trying to override an active_support method. because of that I cant add an attribute or do any changes. (In my example first User class)

thanks

sameera

Answer (score 1):

I am pasting some combination of alias method that can help you

```
class Test
  def simple_method
    puts "I am inside 'simple_method' method"
  end

  def parameter_instance_method(param1)
    puts param1
  end

  def self.class_simple_method
    puts "I am inside 'class_simple_method'"
  end

  def self.parameter_class_method(arg)
    puts arg
  end


  alias_method :simple_method_new, :simple_method

  alias_method :parameter_instance_method_new, :parameter_instance_method

  singleton_class.send(:alias_method, :class_simple_method_new, :class_simple_method)
  singleton_class.send(:alias_method, :parameter_class_method_new, :parameter_class_method)
end

Test.new.simple_method_new
Test.new.parameter_instance_method_new("I am parameter_instance_method")

Test.class_simple_method_new
Test.parameter_class_method_new(" I am parameter_class_method")
```

> OUTPUT

```
I am inside 'simple_method' method
I am parameter_instance_method
I am inside 'class_simple_method'
I am parameter_class_method
```