# combine multiple search results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

first, thank you for your help and support.
after setup a simple search using scenic and textacular. 
i´ve tried to combine the results with a simple combination on the search controller.
the search works very well but, if i search for tag,
i got the

> undefined method `username' for #Tag:0x0000

as i find out many solutions come with concatenating the query and the models are associated.

so in this case, the models are not associated.
so someone can give a tip to how to combine separated models attrs in one query?

**the model:**

```
class Search < ApplicationRecord
    extend Textacular

  belongs_to :searchable, polymorphic: true
   attr_accessor :query


  def results
    if @query.present?
      self.class.search(@query).preload(:searchable).to_a.map!(&:searchable).uniq
    else
      Search.none
    end
  end

end
```

**controller:**

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
respond_to :html


def index
  @users = User.search(params[:search])
  @tags = Tag.search(params[:search])
  @search_results = @users + @tags  

 if params[:search].present?
        @search_results = Search.new(query: params[:search]).results
    else
        @users = User.all
    end

  end

end
```

**the view:**

```
<div>
<% @search_results.each do |r| %>

<%= r.username %>
<%= r.name %>

<% end %> 

</div>
```

Comment: I suspected of this `@search_results = @users + @tags`,  what does each member contains?

Comment: @iGian users => username  and tags => name.
that's it

Comment: Try `<%= r.username if r.respond_to?(:username) %>` and similarly for `r.name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller action, you are first assigning values to `@users` and `@search_results` and then simply overriding either one of them **without using** it. So, i moved the statements a bit to remove any unused assignment of values:

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:search].present?
      @search_results = Search.new(query: params[:search]).results
    else
      @users = User.all
    end

    # Are you sure you still need to set `@users` and `@tags`? Reason: `@search_results` above would already be set if `params[:search]` was present.
    @users ||= User.search(params[:search])    # Assigns only if @users is not previously set
    @tags = Tag.search(params[:search])
    @search_results ||= @users + @tags
  end
end
```

Further improvement can be made if you are using only `@search_results` in your view and **NOT** `@users` and `@tags`:

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @search_results = if params[:search].present?
                        Search.new(query: params[:search]).results
                      else
                        User.all + Tag.all
                      end
  end
end
```

And finally in your view:

```
<div>
  <% @search_results.each do |r| %>
    <% if r.respond_to?(:name) %>
      <%= r.name %>
    <% elsif r.respond_to?(:username) %>
      <%= r.username %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %> 
</div>
```

Comment: Jagdeep Singh thank you very much.
so to show both results tag and users, is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

In controller you have

```
@users = User.search(params[:search])
@tags = Tag.search(params[:search])
@search_results = @users + @tags
```

So, `@users` are members of `User` class and `@tags` are member of `Tag` class.

You are calling `username` attribute on `@search_results`, so you are doing it on `@tags`.

The easy fix is to use two each cycle in view, one for `@users` and one for `@tags`.

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<%= user.username %>
<% end %>
```

And

```
<% @tags.each do |tag| %>
<%= tag.name %>
<% end %>
```

Another fix I think should work is to alias an attribute of Tag or User like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913349/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-alias-to-attributes-in-ruby).